# Is there any method in pyspark to get the name of the university from a url?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
      host                     count
0   xsi12.komaba.ecc.u-tokyo.ac.jp  401
1   sunspot.eds.ecip.nagoya-u.ac.jp 387
2   rungw002.ritsumei.ac.jp         343
```

get the university name from the data frame which is right in front of .ac.jp but after then "next" dot, from back to front e.g. for host `pc021133.shef.ac.jp`, the university is `shef.ac.jp`.

Can someone help me with this, I couldn't find a method to get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `regexp_extract`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('name', F.regexp_extract('host', '([^\\.]*\\.ac\\.jp$)', 1))
```